# .NET fails to start new process in C drive subdirectory

Tags: .net, windows, desktop, uac

I'm writing an updater for my program. The new version of the program is copied into a temp directory (over filesystem). Then the program starts from the temp directory, deletes old version and copies itself into directory. After that the user can start the new version of the program with a button click. It works fine in any folder except with C:\directory (including C:\Program files).

```
dim childProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
childProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
childProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = updateFolder
childProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
childProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
childProcess.Start()
```

I experimented with admin rights (without any success):

```
childProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute
childProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
```

The old version of updater which gets files over ftp could manage this with the C:\directory\ path too.

Has anyone any idea for some workaround. (Because it's necessary to install the program to C:\somedir\ for some reasons.)

Comment: Do you get any exception when running childProcess.Start()?

Comment: It does not thow any exception. it steps over in debuger without any effect